# SUM the result from GROUP BY HAVING

Tags: mysql, group-by, having

Scratching my head on this one.

The following query returns two results 3,5 (there are two teams that occur in the table equal to or more than 3 times)...but I need it to return 8.

I've tried nesting the GROUP BY & HAVING but no luck?

```
SELECT SUM(play_in) AS Total FROM Transfer WHERE id_str='10' GROUP BY team HAVING COUNT(*)>=3
```

Tried this...no response?

```
SELECT SUM(Total) FROM (SELECT SUM(play_in) AS Total FROM Transfer WHERE id_str='10' GROUP BY team HAVING COUNT(*)>=3) AS The_Total
```

Had to add The_Total as without it all I got was "Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: You cannot get the result you need in a single query. You have to `SELECT SUM(Total) FROM (...)` (replace the ellipsis with the query you posted).

Comment: No luck? Amended my initial question

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to the initial statement the following at the end: "WITH ROLLUP". This would add an entry with a total in the results, having null as vale for the team column.

The drawback would be that you cannot show only the entries which have null on the group by column, you have to filter this in a client application.

Comment: GROUP BY team WITH ROLLUP? It accepted it but didn't return a result?